# Very long Google Apps domain alias validation

Tags: google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator, dns

I have already installed Google Apps on my domain `beaumet.fr`, everything works fine.

But I encountered a problem when I tried to add the domain `beaumet.me` as a *domain alias*.

I followed Google instructions and added the following *MX Records* in my zone file:

```
@ 28800 IN MX 1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM. 
@ 28800 IN MX 3 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM. 
@ 28800 IN MX 3 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM. 
@ 28800 IN MX 5 ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM. 
@ 28800 IN MX 5 ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
```

Then I clicked :

```
I have completed these steps
```

I got the message `MX records setup validation in progress...` for two days, then the validation failed.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You're trying to change the top level domain. I don't think that is possible.

Comment: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/apps/u0DZv3hpee8/1BNBVxAPCxA check this once might be helpful

Comment: @vignesh4303 lateron in the discussion, people still face problems....

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra I'm aware I can't change the top level domain and this isn't what I'm trying to do. I just want to add a domain alias.

Comment: Do you own the `beaumet.me`?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra Of course, I've already added the MX records, as you can see [here](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/checkmx/check?domain=beaumet.me).

Comment: @vignesh4303 I've already read almost all the topics on the web concerning this problem... including the one you linked. I didn't find any solution. That's why I posted here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs to [webmasters.] and [sf].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I contacted Google Apps, this is apparently a known bug. The validation seems to fail. Actually, it fails in all cases. So this is not a relevant indicator.

If you can send and receive emails from your domain alias, the validation has succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:

1. Set MX records TTL to 5 minutes.
2. Check if I have a naked domain (eg example.com) with no A record, or a CNAME.

Naked domains must have an A record to work normally.